# Use different fonFamilly in the same line of text, in React native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I need to apply in a sentence two different `fontFamily`.

In the phrase `"String1: second String"`, I need `"string1:"` to be *semibold*, and `"second String"` is *regular*.

```html
<Text
  style={[
    { color: colors.black, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold' },
  ]}>
  String1:
  <Text
    style={[
      { color: colors.black, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular' },
    ]}>
    second String
  </Text>
</Text>
```

The result of the above code puts all text to semibold.

Comment: I still can't do that, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question I needed in React-Native to make a sentence have two different fontFamily.
For this we created a to make the line of text and within that component we put the sentence divided with the different fontFamily. The end result is what is in the image, and the solution the code below.

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYN0c.png)

Solution is...

```html
<Text>
 <Text
   style={[
     { color: colors.black, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold' },
   ]}>
    String1:
   </Text>
   <Text
     style={[
       { color: colors.black, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Regular' },
     ]}>
     second String
   </Text>
 </Text>
```

Comment: Please include more context about what you changed and why it worked. I suggest you read [answer]. I know this is your own question, but other readers in the future might need to understand.